# What's the easiest or cheapest Ascended backpiece?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've found it particularly straight-forward to get ascended pieces in all slots. All slots except the back.

<kbd>**Weapons**</kbd>    <kbd>Crafting</kbd>                      
<kbd>**Armor**</kbd>      <kbd>Crafting</kbd>                      
<kbd>**Accessories**</kbd><kbd>Laurels or Guild Commendations</kbd>
<kbd>**Rings**</kbd>      <kbd>Laurel Merchant or BUY-4373</kbd>   
<kbd>**Amulet**</kbd>     <kbd>Laurel Merchant</kbd>               
<kbd>**Back**</kbd>       <kbd>????</kbd>

There appear to be many different options for back pieces, however, their acquisition methods seems to be varied, with some taking more effort than others.

If my primary interest is to get an Ascended back piece, what is the easiest option?

Comment: Consider the path of Mawdrey... I think you'll end up spending close (shy of 50g?) to the cost of others unless you want to farm fractals for quite some time. You'll grow a cool plant that eats bloodstone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have differents options, depending on what you are doing in the game (fractals or not), those are the easiest/cheapest ones :

1. [Prototype Fractal Capacitor (Ascended)](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Prototype_Fractal_Capacitor_%28Ascended%29) :

   - 1  [Vial of Condensed Mists Essence](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Vial_of_Condensed_Mists_Essence) (from fractals 1-9)
   - 1  [Gift of Ascension](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gift_of_Ascension) (500 Fractal Relics from BUY-4373)
   - 40 [Crystal](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Crystal) or 240 [Philosopher's Stone](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Philosopher%27s_Stone) (from Miyani)
   - 1 [Prototype fractal capacitator](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Prototype_Fractal_Capacitor) (1,350 Fractal Relics from BUY-4373)
2. [There with Yakkington: A Traveler's Tale](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/There_with_Yakkington:_A_Traveler%27s_Tale)

   - 1 [Vial of Condensed Mists Essence](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Vial_of_Condensed_Mists_Essence)
   - 40 [Crystal](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Crystal)
   - 50 [Glob of Ectoplasm](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glob_of_Ectoplasm)
   - 250 [Vicious Claw](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Vicious_Claw)
3. [Quiver of a Thousand Arrows](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Quiver_of_a_Thousand_Arrows)

   - 1 [Vial of Condensed Mists Essence](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Vial_of_Condensed_Mists_Essence)
   - 240 [Philosopher's Stone](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Philosopher%27s_Stone)
   - 50 [Glob of Ectoplasm](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glob_of_Ectoplasm)
   - 250 [Vicious Claw](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Vicious_Claw)

They all need to be made at the mystic forge.